# Open Alteryx .yxdb file in Python?

Tags: python, database, import, format, alteryx

Is there a way to import .yxdb (Alteryx database files) into Pandas/Python, without using Alteryx as a go-between?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is no, not at this time.

Longer answer: the raw C++ for .yxdb support is [available on github](https://github.com/AlteryxNed/Open_AlteryxYXDB), as it was open sourced in order to adhere to R licensing when Alteryx hooked into R.  See [this link](https://inspiringingenuity.net/2015/05/08/alteryx-open-source-yxdb/) where Ned Harding explains it all in his blog. So basically, everything is there for someone to build Python support by utilizing the open source C++ ... but nobody has done so just yet.

Answer (score 2):

Not python specific, a [YXDB to SQLite DB command line](https://github.com/kljh/Open_AlteryxYXDB/releases) based on the C++ library open sourced by Alteryx.

Limitations:

- Not a Python module: use subprocess to invoke the command, then pandas/sqlite3 to read from the SQLite database file.
- Read YXDB into SQLite only: write to YXDB not implemented (altough the alteryx library would allow it)

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the fork.