# Opening Alteryx .yxdb files in R

Tags: r, database, import, format, alteryx

Similar to the question below, I was wondering whether there is a way to open .yxdb files in R?

[Open Alteryx .yxdb file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750487/open-alteryx-yxdb-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

YXDB is Alteryx's own native format.  I haven't seen or heard of anything else that can open it.

You could change your workflow to write to a CSV (or other compatible file) as well as writing to the YXDB file.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way yet for R to read yxdb files. I also export my Alteryx workflows to CSVs or use the R tool, read.Alteryx, and saveRDS to save it as a fast-loading binary file.